# What is the proper way to delay with cancellation support inside of a task execution delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I don't see any specific mention either on MSDN or here about how to accomplish this. The use case is somewhat obscure, but still valid I suspect.

```
var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Task.Delay(1000, cancel.Token).Wait(); }, cancel.Token);
cancel.CancelAfter(100);
task.Wait();
```

The above code will attempt to cancel a `task` that contains a ***detached*** child delay task after 100 milliseconds, and wait for the `task` to complete which will generate an `AggregateException` (due to the cancellation). The problem with this is that the `task` becomes faulted instead of cancelled. This is expected behaviour because the delay task is not attached to the parent `task`, even though both share the same cancellation token.

My question relates specifically to how you would go about attaching a `Task.Delay` to a task that is already running. Is it possible to even do this if you had access to the parent task? If it isn't possible, or not possible without access to the parent task instance what is the proper way to handle this scenario?

The best work around I could come up with was to wrap the delay task's `Wait` in a try/finally block, and explicitly attempt to bubble up the task cancellation.

```
try { Task.Delay(1000, cancel.Token).Wait(); } finally { cancel.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); }
```

While effective, it doesn't feel quite right, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to accomplish this. The desired outcome is that the parent task goes to `Canceled` instead of `Faulted` if cancellation occurs. So if the genesis of the cancellation occurs in a detached child task, the parent task should still transition to `Canceled`.

***NOTE***: I left out async/await here on purpose, just because it doesn't appear to change the problem or the result. If that's not the case please provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a task is considered canceled when an `OperationCanceledException` is thrown and uncaught inside it and its associated `CancellationToken` is canceled.

In your case the exception being thrown is `AggregateException` that *contains* a `TaskCanceledException` (which is an `OperationCanceledException`) instead of the `TaskCanceledException` directly.

There's a simple way to fix that. Instead of synchronously blocking with `Task.Wait` which wraps any exceptions in an `AggregateException` wrapper you can use `task.GatAwaiter().GetResult()`. That is what `await` uses in `async-await`. It throws the original exception and if there were multiple ones it throws the first:

```
var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Task.Delay(1000, cancel.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }, cancel.Token);
cancel.CancelAfter(100);
task.Wait();
```

If you would have used `async-await` you wouldn't have this issue as unlike `Task.Wait` it throws the `TaskCanceledException` itself:

```
var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
var task = Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000, cancel.Token), cancel.Token);
cancel.CancelAfter(100);
task.Wait();
```

---

I assume this is just an example. Real production code shouldn't resembles this as you're blocking synchronously on an asynchronous operation which in turn blocks synchronously on an asynchronous operation.

Comment: The `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is precisely what I was looking for.

The code is actually to write a test that confirms a started task can be cancelled. The delay is simply there to simulate cancelling a task that is in the middle of executing its (long running) delegate. In my test I have some post delay statements that help confirm the delegate is actually cancelled (by the statements not being executed), which precludes me from using code like in your 2nd block with `Task.Run`.

I created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uvia02) to showcase the whole issue and its resolution.